# Geth - Unclean shutdown detected

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-clique

I am facing  **Unclean shutdown detected**  in my private chain. The nodes was shut down suddenly due to some unavoidable reasons but when I restart the nodes new blocks are not mined. Now, what can I do to run the chain with existing data?

```
INFO [05-03|03:08:00.959] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [05-03|03:08:00.962] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [05-03|03:08:00.962] Using leveldb as db engine
INFO [05-03|03:08:00.972] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [05-03|03:08:00.975] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [05-03|03:08:00.976] Using leveldb as the backing database
INFO [05-03|03:08:00.976] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/opt/blockchain2041/current-node/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=2048
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.036] Using LevelDB as the backing database
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.036] Found legacy ancient chain path          location=/opt/blockchain2041/current-node/geth/chaindata/ancient
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.045] Opened ancient database                  database=/opt/blockchain2041/current-node/geth/chaindata/ancient readonly=false
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.060] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=2041 dbversion=8
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061] Chain ID:  2041 (unknown)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061] Consensus: Clique (proof-of-authority)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061] Pre-Merge hard forks (block based):
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Homestead:                   #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/homestead.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Tangerine Whistle (EIP 150): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/tangerine-whistle.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Spurious Dragon/1 (EIP 155): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Spurious Dragon/2 (EIP 158): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Byzantium:                   #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/byzantium.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Constantinople:              #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/constantinople.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Petersburg:                  #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/petersburg.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Istanbul:                    #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/istanbul.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - Berlin:                      #<nil> (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/berlin.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]  - London:                      #<nil> (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/london.md)
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061]
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.061] The Merge is not yet available for this network!
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.062]  - Hard-fork specification: https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/paris.md
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.062]
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.062] Post-Merge hard forks (timestamp based):
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.062]
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.062] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.062]
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.064] Loaded most recent local header          number=69400 hash=5005a2..3a38a5 td=113,046 age=1mo2w4d
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.064] Loaded most recent local block           number=23726 hash=654cb1..556733 td=47443   age=2y2mo2d
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.064] Loaded most recent local snap block      number=69400 hash=5005a2..3a38a5 td=113,046 age=1mo2w4d
WARN [05-03|03:08:01.253] Failed to load snapshot                  err="missing or corrupted snapshot"
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.254] Rebuilding state snapshot
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.254] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.254] Resuming state snapshot generation       root=a89299..f2a480 accounts=0 slots=0 storage=0.00B dangling=0 elapsed="585.632µs"
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.255] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [05-03|03:08:01.256] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
WARN [05-03|03:08:01.257] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2023-05-03T03:05:32-0400 age=2m29s
WARN [05-03|03:08:01.257] Unclean shutdown detected                booted=2023-05-03T03:06:02-0400 age=1m59s
```

Comment: Bug ? No more disk space ? No RAM/CPU available ? I don't think there is a way for us to help you there. A quick google search does not give much info. https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/26334 https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/23232